# Can the CP solver be initialised at a specific point?

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

I am using the CP-Sat solver to optimise a timetable I am making. However, this now takes a long time to solve. Is it possible to seed the solver with an old result, to act as a starting point, with the goal of reducing the time required to find the optimal result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at this solution hinting example:

- https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/docs/model.md#solution-hinting

```py
num_vals = 3
x = model.NewIntVar(0, num_vals - 1, 'x')
y = model.NewIntVar(0, num_vals - 1, 'y')
z = model.NewIntVar(0, num_vals - 1, 'z')

model.Add(x != y)

model.Maximize(x + 2 * y + 3 * z)

# Solution hinting: x <- 1, y <- 2
model.AddHint(x, 1)
model.AddHint(y, 2)
```

Edit: you should also try to

- Reduce the amount of variables.
- Reduce the domain of the integer variables.
- Run the solver with multiples threads using`solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 8`.
- Prefer boolean over integer variables/contraints.
- Set redundant constraints and/or symmetry breaking constraints.
- Segregate your problem and merge the results.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'redundant constraints and/or symmetry breaking constraints'?